# How do you tell Maven which Tests to run?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and have reached the testing portion. When I create the `HelloControllerTest` file as well as a `HelloControllerIT` file in my test directory at `src/test/java/hello/` only the `HelloControllerTest` test runs. However, if I rename the second file to end with the word `Test`, such as `HelloController2Test`, then it also runs. I'm running the tests from command line during the Maven build with `mvn clean verify`. I'm running Maven 3.3.9 on OSX.

I have two main questions: how does Maven know which tests to run? And, more importantly, how do I tell Maven to run other tests? Below is my `pom.xml`, taken directly from the [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) will, [by default](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), attempt to execute all tests that follow the pattern of `Test*.java` or `*Test.java` or `*TestCase.java`. It ignores your `HelloControllerIT` very intentionally, as by standard maven convention, that is not a **unit** test, it is an **integration** test. The maven-surefire-plugin is enabled by default in all maven projects.

There is a separate plugin, [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/), used to run integration tests, denoted ([by default](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)) by the naming pattern `IT*.java` or `*IT.java` or `*ITCase.java`. It runs during the `integration-test` phase of the build rather than the `test` phase. However, unlike maven-surefire-plugin, you need to explicitly enable it. (I don't know why this is.)

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Add maven-failsafe-plugin to your project, and your integration test should run just fine.

Comment: Just a note: I had some tests that matched the naming pattern that did not run. Turned out the class definition was not _public_ (was default package level). So check that. Also, the method names in the class must also match the test* patterns. Even if JUnit works with @Test, does not mean that Surefire will run them

Answer (score 3):

1) how does Maven know which tests to run? By default, maven executes all tests. I mean, all test that Maven finds.

2) how do I tell Maven to run other tests? To execute a specific test class (eg. HelloController2Test), you can do this :

```
mvn -Dtest=HelloController2Test test
```

[Reference doc here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

[One other explanation(from the well known site MKYong)](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-run-unit-test-with-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

Maven surefire plugin is responsible for running tests. The following link should answer your question: [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Answer (score 0):

2023 update: According to [this Apache doc](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html) this is the way to go:

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

I tested it and works well